# Pandas (and seaborn) violinplot of state vs. year

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm learning Pandas, (watching [these helpful videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCgJGsg0Xa4)) and currently playing around with a UFO sighting table

```
import pandas as pd
ufo = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/ufo.csv')
ufo.head()

ufo.Time    = pd.to_datetime(ufo.Time)
ufo['Year'] = ufo.Time.dt.year
ufo.head()
```

Now, I'd like to use Seaborn to make a [violinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) of each state (on the x-axis) and the year (on the y-axis). Hence the plot shows the frequency density of sightings at any given year, in any given state.

If I use

```
ufo.State.value_counts()
```

I can get a Pandas Series of all the counts for each state. But how do I separate this data by year? I somehow need to get data with the ufo sightings per year per state?

Am I on the right track to create a Seaborn violinplot? Or going in completely the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example shown in [`violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) documentation of the following example:

> ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)

You can directly assign your desired columns into x-axis by supplying the column name into `x=` and y-axis to the `y=` parameter. The following code shows the data structure of `tips` variable.

```
In [   ]: tips.head()
Out[   ]: 
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
```

Your question is to plot using `violinplot`, having x-axis to show `ufo.State` and y-axis to show `ufo.Year`. Therefore, I believe [`ufo.State.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) is unnecessary, or even [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) since the `ufo` data is already well described and satisfy violinplot's parameter format.

You can achieve it by directly supplying both `ufo.columnName` into `x=` and `y=`. See the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ufo = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/ufo.csv')

ufo.head()

                   City Colors Reported Shape Reported State  \
0                Ithaca             NaN       TRIANGLE    NY   
1           Willingboro             NaN          OTHER    NJ   
2               Holyoke             NaN           OVAL    CO   
3               Abilene             NaN           DISK    KS   
4  New York Worlds Fair             NaN          LIGHT    NY   

                 Time  Year  
0 1930-06-01 22:00:00  1930  
1 1930-06-30 20:00:00  1930  
2 1931-02-15 14:00:00  1931  
3 1931-06-01 13:00:00  1931  
4 1933-04-18 19:00:00  1933  


ufo.Time    = pd.to_datetime(ufo.Time)
ufo['Year'] = ufo.Time.dt.year

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.violinplot(x=ufo.State, y=ufo.Year)
# ax = sns.violinplot(x='State', y='Year', data=ufo)    # Works the same with the code one line above
plt.show()
```

[image: Violinplot of UFO sightings]